# Is there a Python fstring or string formatting equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, string-formatting

I'm working on a project in C++ and I needed to make a string that has elements of an array in it. I know in python you have things like `sting formatting` and `fstrings`, but I don't know if C++ has any equivalent. I have no earthly idea as to whether or not that's a thing, so I figured this is the best place to ask. I'm making a tic-tac-toe game and I have the board made and I have the positions on the board made. All I'm trying to do is optimize the board so that I can call it from one function in another function and have the parent function return the board so I can work with it. My basic idea for how to do this was to take the board and turn it all into one big string with a bunch of newlines in it and the array elements in it. I also made it in a function so I can just call it wherever I need it and just have it there. Here is the board function I made:

```
void board(){
char board_pos[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << "  " << board_pos[0][0] << "  |  " << board_pos[0][1] << "  |  " << board_pos[0][2] << "  " << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << "-----------------" << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << "  " << board_pos[1][0] << "  |  " << board_pos[1][1] << "  |  " << board_pos[1][2] << "  " << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << "-----------------" << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
cout << "  " << board_pos[2][0] << "  |  " << board_pos[2][1] << "  |  " << board_pos[2][2] << "  " << endl;
cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
}
```

Edit: I got it figured out thanks to the help of you guys, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Are you asking for ways to improve this? See [codereview.se]

Comment: If you want a `string` rather than writing to the console, read up on `std::ostringstream`, then replace the calls to `cout` with a string stream. When you're done, you get the `string` from the string stream.

Comment: *"I have no earthly idea as to how to do this"* -- No, you do have an idea. See the part of your question that begins *"My basic idea for how to do this was"*. If you're not sure what to do next, you might need to go back to your design and write it out in more detail. Sometimes you have to get down to painstaking detail to see what the obstacle is.

Comment: Ok, I just found out that this question was reopened so that's nice, but I figured out how to do what I was asking about on my own. I appreciate all the help none the less. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just return the type that you use to hold the board. In your case you started with `char[3][3]`.

I would write that using the C++11 `array`:

```
using Row   = std::array<char, 3>;
using Board = std::array<Row, 3>;
```

Now you can make all kinds of functions:

```
void move(char player, Board const& b, int row, int col);
bool is_game_over(Board const&);
void print(Board const& b);
```

Etc.

Your print function could be:

```
void print(Board const& b)
{
    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
    auto print_row = [](Row const& row) {
        std::cout << "  " << row[0] << "  |  " << row[1] << "  |  " << row[2]
                  << "  \n";
    };
    print_row(b[0]);
    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
    std::cout << "-----------------\n";
    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
    print_row(b[1]);
    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
    std::cout << "-----------------\n";
    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
    print_row(b[2]);
    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
}
```

See it [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c875651ead208909)

Prints

```
     |     |
  1  |  2  |  3
     |     |
-----------------
     |     |
  4  |  5  |  6
     |     |
-----------------
     |     |
  7  |  8  |  9
     |     |
```

Comment: As a toy example here's how I'd probably approach it, simplifying the board to a flat array: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fce09f372d82ffe demo https://imgur.com/a/GMl85a0

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used your code and tried to modify it to get the results I was looking for, but I couldn't get the output to look right. I really appreciate the help none the less, and I just wanted to let you know that I did end up figuring out how to do this thanks to your help. Thank you so much for everything it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @SentBySunlight that is nice to hear. Thanks for the kind words